# I am getting error "ModelForm has no model class specified"

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django and I'm a beginner. I don't understand what the problem is in my code. I get this error when I try create reviews:

> ModelForm has no model class specified

I  don't understand where the problem is.

```
    def createreview(request, movie_id):
    movie = get_object_or_404(Movie, pk=movie_id)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'createreview.html', {'form':ReviewForm(),
                                                     'movie': movie})
    else:
        try:
            form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
            newReview = form.save(commit=True)
            newReview.user = request.user
            newReview.movie = movie
            newReview.save()
            return redirect('detail', Review.movie.id)
        except ValueError:
            return render(request, 'createreview.html', {'form':ReviewForm(),
                                                         'error':'bad data passed in'})

class ReviewForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['text'].widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control'})
        self.fields['watchAgain'].widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-check-input'})

    class Meta:
        models = Review
        fields = ['text', 'watchAgain']
        labels = {'watchAgain': ('Watch Again')}
        widgets = {'text': Textarea(attrs={'rows': 4}), }

class Review(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    watchAgain = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: it is `model = ...`, not `models = ...`.

Comment: Authors here don't have to have perfect English, but please do at least use an English spelling checker.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ReviewForm` does not have a model class because you set `models = Review` instead of `model = Review` in its `class Meta`.